# How to get only the first list element in menu of unordered list in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need to get the first element in the list of unordered lists. I used bellow code and getting all list items as output. Then I click f12 and executed this code [image description output of this code][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ4qn.png`jQuery(window).resize(function() {`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
jQuery(".mean-nav>ul>li:first").click(function(){
  alert(jQuery(this).text());
   });
    });
     },2000);
});

</script>

  </head>
<body>
<div>
 <!--<div class="leader1">REgister</div>
 <div class="leader2">Login</div>
  <div class="leader3">Call Us</div>-->
   <div class="mean-nav">
    <ul>
     <li>1
     <ul>

        <li> aa</li>
        <li> bb</li>
        <li> cc</li>
        <li> dd</li>
        <li> ee</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
       <li>4</li>
       <li>5</li>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(".mean-nav > ul > li:first-child").click(...` should be the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As Wax already mentioned, using a selector combination of

```
$('.mean-nav > ul > li:first-child').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

will search for every element containing the class `mean-nav`, inside search for a directly following `ul` and inside search for a directly following `li`, but only the first occurence is going to be handled. `:first-child` provides the same functionality it's JavaScript equivalent `:nth-child(1)` does.

However, the `:first-child` selector is able to find *multiple* elements, so if you had multiple `ul` inside your element with `mean-nav` containing at least one `li` each, you would find multiple elements.

The `:first` selector does something different - it finds the first occurence of your selector and stops right after - without the risk of finding multiple elements.

Applying that to an example:

```
[...]
<div class="mean-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>ASDF</li>
        <li>BDGF</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="mean-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>2345</li>
        <li>9887</li>
    </ul>
</div>
[...]
```

in this example, using both selectors you would get the following results:

```
$('.mean-nav > ul > li:first-child').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

would log into console two times: 'ASDF' and '2345' - while

```
$('.mean-nav > ul > li:first').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

would only log once: 'ASDF'.

In your case `:first-child` works just the way `:first` would, but best practice would probably be to use `:first`, as you want to find a single element only anyways.

**Edit:** in your original post, you are not closing the `<ul>`

**Edit 2:** remember that the `>` selector searches for *directly following* elements, so you cannot find nested elements unless you leave the `>` step out or specify the selection

**Edit 3:** as op wants to select the *1* in his ul only, without the appended ul, which is still part of the li containing 1, I believe he has to hack this a little bit:

```
$(function() {
    console.log($('.mean-nav > ul > li:first').text().replace($('.mean-nav > ul > li:first > ul').text(), '').trim());
});
```

Let's rip this apart:

- `console.log` logs into the console
- `$('.mean-nav > ul > li:first').text()` returns `1 aa bb cc ddee` with a lot of whitespace
- `x.replace(y, z)` replaces each occurence of `y` with `z` in `x`
- `$('.mean-nav > ul > li:first > ul').text()` returns `aa bb cc ddee` with a lot of whitespace
- `x.trim()` removes all newlines, spaces and tabs at the start and end of a string

So what this does is cut the content of the *ul* inside your *li:first* out of the content of your *li:first*, leaving you with, in this example, *1*

Comment: Thank you @N.M, i have like this structure and only first element should be display. <div class="mean-nav">
                                <ul>
                                                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
       <ul>
       <li> aa</li>
       <li> bb</li>
       <li> cc</li>
       <li> dd</li>
       <li> ee</li>
       </ul>
                                                <li>2</li>
                                                <li>3</li>
                                                <li>4</li>
                                    </ul>

Comment: That's what both selectors do in your case.

Comment: but @N.M, iam getting both first element 1 and its sub menu aa,bb,cc,dd also.

Comment: Please edit your question with updated code and the JQuery-selector you are using as well as what you are executing.

Comment: @SaiVijay I updated my answer to better suit your problem. There might be a better solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mean-nav ul li:first').click(function(){
   //Do your stuff
});
```

You can also target other children using nth-child(n). For eg.,

```
$('.mean-nav ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
   //Do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Nimsrules, if i have first element along with its sub elements then i need only first element then how can i get??

Comment: @SaiVijay, that's what the first line is for

Comment: after using $('.mean-nav ul li:first').click(function(){ first element and its sub elements i am getting. added sanpshot to the question, with updated code.

Comment: `$('.mean-nav > ul > li:first')` This will make sure that only the immediate child element is selected

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

> 1)    $(".mean-nav > ul> li:first-child")

**OR**

> 2)    $(".mean-nav > ul> li:nth-child(1)")

**OR, If you want select first li**

> 3)   $(".mean-nav > ul > li:nth-of-type(1)")

Comment: Thank you @ehsan, i have structure like first element and its have some sub elements then i need to display only the first element. present getting first element with its sub elements. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

To access the first li of ul you need `first-child` selector

```
jQuery(".mean-nav>ul>li:first-child").click(function(){
  alert(jQuery(this).text());
   });
    });
     },2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul, i have structure like first element and its have some sub elements then i need to display only the first element. present getting first element with its sub elements. how can i do this?

Comment: could you elaborate using jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-first for get only first element.

```
jQuery(".mean-nav>ul>li:first").click(function(){});
```

Please Check after resize window.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery(".mean-nav>ul>li:first").click(function(){
          alert(jQuery(this).text());
          return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  </head>
<body>
<div>
 <!--<div class="leader1">REgister</div>
 <div class="leader2">Login</div>
  <div class="leader3">Call Us</div>-->
   <div class="mean-nav">
    <ul>
     <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
       <li>4</li>
       <li>5</li>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaydeep, i have structure like first element and its have some sub elements then i need to display only the first element. present getting first element with its sub elements. how can i do this?